# How can i know which message the user replied to with WhatsApp API and Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am developing an online invitation system using WhatsApp API, Firestore, and Google Cloud Functions. My system allows guests to RSVP to event invitations via WhatsApp quick reply buttons. However, I'm facing an issue with guests who are invited to multiple events.

For the setup,

Database Structure: I have a clients collection in Firestore. Each client document contains their guests.
RSVP Processing: A Google Cloud Function listens for WhatsApp API webhook responses. It checks the phone number in the JSON response and creates a document in a bucket collection with the guest's RSVP status.
Issue:

When a guest, say John, is invited to two different events (e.g., Wedding A and Wedding B) and responds differently to each (Yes to A, No to B), the system does not differentiate between these responses. It updates John's RSVP in the bucket collection based on the latest response, affecting both events. This results in both events seeing the same RSVP status for John, which is incorrect.

What i want to happen is i want the system to handle each event's RSVP independently. So, if John RSVPs 'Yes' to Wedding A and 'No' to Wedding B, each event should only reflect the corresponding response. Additionally, if John changes his response to a particular event, it should update only that event's RSVP status.

So, how can I modify my Firestore structure or Cloud Function to correctly associate each RSVP response with its respective event, especially for guests invited to multiple events? Is there a way to differentiate responses based on the event in the webhook payload, or should I restructure my database to better handle these scenarios?

Current Technologies:

Firestore
Google Cloud Functions
WhatsApp API

Thank you

My current plan is to have a big spreadsheet of all guests. When i notice a guest is invited to 2 events. I will try to manually send them a different template and keep track of their respones
Ex, John will receive template A with quick replies being Coming, Not sure for event A. Then for Event B they will receive Template B with it's quick replies being Yes, no. From there i will track which buttons they choose manually!

Answer (score 0):

When sending the invitation message you could use a distinct ID for the interactive-message quick-reply buttons. Distinct ID for yes button and no button for each wedding.

Afterwards once the user responds by clicking on the quick-reply button, your web-hook will receive the ID which was clicked, and you could correlate on which event they responded to.

More details in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/webhooks/components#messages-object